# How to disable E901 SyntaxError in flake8

Tags: python, python-2.6, pep8, flake8

I have an intentional syntax error in python code.
The python file is a template where certain values would be later substituted with real python code. Those parts of the python should be ignored during checkup.

Sample to reproduce

```
from --syntax-error-- import --syntax--error--  # noqa
# second attempt:
from --syntax-error2-- import --syntax--error2--  # noqa: E901
```

I am trying to disable E901 but noqa command is ignored.
Is it possible to disable any other way?

Flake8 version is 2.6.2

Comment: Please explain your intention!

Comment: I added inline.

Comment: A syntax error usually stops the parser since it does not have a defined state anymore. So I guess you won't be able to just jump over it. But I'm wondering what you need the template for. Python is a very dynamic language and in many years of Python I had no need for a code template so far.

Comment: I do not need template for python code itself. I need template for the imported c++ library, I have 2 versions of the same c++ library, with almost same python wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You should lint the version produced by the template, not the template itself. Flake8 cannot skip over SyntaxErrors as we try to build an Abstract Syntax Tree which requires a valid Python file.

Comment: You guys are doing great job, but Isn't it own limitation? Note, I am not insisting. And btw you have parsed correctly the rest of the file.

Comment: Some checks use the AST which requires the syntax to be valid Python. Other checks parse the file differently using a far less strict parsing engine. That means that you will not be able to get the benefit of some checks but we degrade service gracefully.

Comment: Since my usage is lonely, I believe it does not make sense to invest your time in it.